# Using proc means to get the average fish weight by species in sashelp table fish

Tags: sas

Here's what I'm doing but it throws an error saying.  It will print the first two but fails after that.

ERROR: Data set WORK.FISH is not sorted in ascending sequence. The current BY group has Species = Whitefish and the next BY group 
 has Species = Parkki.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
data fish;
    set sashelp.fish;
    run;


proc means data = fish;
var weight;
by species;
run;
```

Comment: Use the `class` statement instead of `by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BY` statement in `proc means` assumes that the dataset is sorted by the `BY` variable. Just add a `proc sort` before `proc means`.

```
data fish;
    set sashelp.fish;
run;

proc sort data=fish;
    by species;
run;

proc means data = fish;
var weight;
by species;
run;
```

Another way of doing it without the `proc sort` is to use a `class` statement:

```
proc means data=sashelp.fish mean;
class species;
var weight;
run;
```